# Docker + MacOS : Montar Volume fora da pasta root ou Users

Tags: docker

Estou tendo um problema na hora de realizar a montagem por vinculação no Docker através do comando:

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 -v "$(pwd)/path:/path conteiner_name
```

Acontece que o diretório não é montado no conteiner.

Isso é devido ao diretório retornado de `$(pwd)` que é de uma outra partição no meu sistema operacional *host*. Porém, fazer o mesmo procedimento na pasta `/Users` no OSX, ele faz a vinculação normalmente. Meu HD está dividido em

```
SSD1 - Instalado o docker (S.O Host), boot2docker, etc
HDD1 - Contém os arquivos do conteiner, DockerFile, etc.
```

Se eu dar o *build* para criar o container no HDD1 e dar o *run*, ele não irá buscar o diretório através do `$(pwd)/path:/path`, mas se eu mover os mesmos arquivos para o SSD1, ele funciona perfeitamente.

Será que é algo de permissão? Li na documentação do Docker que, por padrão, pode ser compartilhado as pastas `/Users`, `/etc`, `/tmp`...

Comment: qual versão do docker você esta usando eu uso esta no mac (Version 17.03.1-ce-mac12 (17661) Channel: stable d1db12684b), nesta versão vc tem a opção de adicionar as pastas compartilhadas no meu caso adicionei a pasta /Volumes e consigo usar normalmente os volumes que estão fora das pastas padrões.

Comment: Olá, estou usando a versão17.05.0-ce, qual o comando para adicionar as outras pastas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu configuro via interface, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: Preferences]

Comment: Qual o client que você está usando para o docker?

Comment: Version 17.03.1-ce-mac12 (17661)
Channel: stable
d1db12684b

Comment: Eu tentei achar esse client gui, para adicionar as pastas. Aqui eu não achei. Instalei a versão do docker toolbox.

Comment: @Rodrigo, você instalou esta versão: ( https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg )

Comment: agora deu certo, na verdade eu estava seguindo através do livro "Usando Docker - Mouat" e lá ele comenta sobre o Docker toolbox, vem algumas ferramentas a mais para o Docker, como Kitematic. Muito obrigado!!